Is there a way to not construct a string object when querying a map with string key?
Let's say I have a map or unordered_map that has template types <std::string, int>. Now I want to query whether the container contains the "some_name" key. So I use the .find function that takes a const std::string&, however it's very unnecessary to do dynamic heap allocations such as happens when you create a std::string object, which must be constructed in this case when I pass the "some_name" to the function.
I thought about storing they keys as string_views, but I don't think this is a good idea as I think the map entries should store copies of the string. However since the find function strictly takes std::string& what can I do about this? Consider both the cases where I have a string literal, as the example I gave above, and for already existing strings like string views, pointers to strings or whatever, and I don't want to construct an std::string.

The missing bit of data from the linked post is that some containers got transparent operations only in C++20 (and then some more again in C++23). So check against the standard you are using. Also, when it comes to std::string, a dynamic allocation is not guaranteed due to the small string optimization. Depending on your data, the discussion may be moot.
